# mocking external service with mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I have an application with following structure:

> Client class:

```
class Client{
    private Requests requests;
    private Settings settings;
    protected Client(Settings settings){
        this.settings = settings;
        this.requests = new Requests(settings);
    }
    public Requests getRequests(){
        return requests;
    }
}
```

> Requests class:

```
class Requests{
    private RequestsHandler requestsHandler;
    private Settings settings;

    protected Requests(Settings settings){
        this.requestHandler = new RequestHandler();
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    public Bicycles getBicycles(BicyclesParameters bicycleParams){
        return requestsHandler.callService(bicycleParams, settings, "service/getBicycles", Bicycles.class)
    }
}
```

And my

> RequestsHandler class:

```
class RequestsHandler{
        public BaseResponse callService(BaseParams params, Settings settings, String serviceURL, Class<? extends BaseResponse> responseType ) {

            here I use RestTemplate to get data from external Service

        }
    }
```

In my Unit tests, I would like to mock the data from external service, so I did as following: 
create a mocking *RequestsHandler* object, mock the *callService* method and register this mock object with *@Bean*:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public RequestsHandler requestsHandler() {
        RequestsHandler requestsHandler = Mockito.mock(RequestsHandler.class);
        when(requestsHandler.callService(new BicyclesParameters(), new Settings(),
                "/service/getBicyles", Bicycles.class))
                        .thenReturn(new Bicycles().setBicyclesList(new Bicycle[] {new Bicycle(), new Bicycle()}));
        return requestsHandler;
    }
}
```

and my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
public class TestGetBicycles{

    @Test
    public void testGetBicycles() {
        Client = new Client(new Settings);
        Bicycles bicycles = client.getRequests.getBicycles(new BicyclesParamters());
        assertNotNull(bicycles.getBicyclesList());
    }

}
```

But when I run the test, I had two problems:

1. I become an

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException

, I have no idea why but when I changed my mock  object to:

```
 when(requestsHandler.callService(any(), any(),
                any(), any()))
                        .thenReturn(new Bicycles().setBicyclesList(new Bicycle[] {new Bicycle(), new Bicycle()}));
```

the error went away, but

2. the result I become is not the mock result, instead the result from the external service. This means the mock object was not taken into account.

Can anyone help me at these points? This is my first time working with Mockito so I am so confused now.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a mock but this is never used in the scope of the executed method.

In fact your problem is that you want to mock an object that is created inside a object created during the invocation of the tested method :

```
protected Requests(Settings settings){
    this.requestHandler = new RequestHandler(); // <- You want to mock this field
    this.settings = settings;
}
```

It is not possible with plain mockito. In your case you have two ways :

1) refactor your code to provide an **additional** constructor that accepts the `RequestHandler` as parameter.  In your case `Client` and `Requests` could accept `RequestHandler`.
For example for `Client` :

```
protected Client(Settings settings, RequestsHandler requestHandler){
    this.settings = settings;
    this.requests = new Requests(settings, requestHandler);
}
```

and you test could look like :

```
@Mock
RequestsHandler requestsHandlerMock;
...
@Test
public void testGetBicycles() {
    Client = new Client(new Settings(), requestsHandlerMock);
    Bicycles bicycles = client.getRequests.getBicycles(new BicyclesParamters());
    //...
}
```

2) Using libraries that relies on reflection and byte code generation (as CGLib)  at runtime. PowerMock and PowerMockito are well known in Java for that.

Personally I favor the refactoring as it is possible. It makes the code always clearer and cleaner. In fact these libraries are not bad in themselves but it may create some technical debt as by using them too often you may be encouraged to *cheat* with the help of the library instead of improving the API of the code to test.

Comment: I see, I just tried your 1st solution, but I still got the org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException, do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Didn't you mix argument matchers with no argument matchers such as `when.myMethod(any(), any(), new Foo())` ?

Comment: here is my mock: when(requestsHandler.callService(new BicyclesParameters(), new Settings(),
                "/service/getBicyles", Bicycles.class))

Comment: It is not this issue. Do you not have a  error message with the exception ?

Comment: ah no I am sorry I did make mistake, yes I used a mix argument machers here: when(requestsHandler.callService(new BicyclesParameters(), any(), "/service/getBicyles", Bicycles.class))

Comment: Ok ! You cannot do that. You should enclose argument references to no argument matchers by `Mockito.eq(...)` such as : `when(requestsHandler.callService(eq(new BicyclesParameters()), any(), eq("/service/getBicyles"), eq(Bicycles.class)))`

Comment: Hi davidxxx, may I ask you one more thing? Assume that in the RequestsHandler class I have another method ABC which will be called inside of the callService(). How can I mock this method instead of mocking the whole callService method? I mean the implementation is unchanged: I called the requestsHandler.callService() and right now I am mocking the callService(), but what if  I am mocking only a method inside of the callService() instead of the whole big method, is it possible?

Comment: Sure. You could use the `Spy` option of Mockito that allows to create a partial mock of the object under test (you could find examples with Google). In this way you could mock only this method in the `RequestsHandler` method. Note that I rarely use it because API (public methods here) should be tested as a whole by mocking only the dependencies. Mocking a part of the method under test means not fully tested it. Are you sure that you really need to mock this method ? Could this method not be moved into another class ?  In this way mocking the dependency of this class would be straights.

Comment: These are just pointers but as a public method does as many things as you need to mock its own processings in your test, it is legitimate to wonder if a refactoring is not required.

Comment: Hi davidxxx, thanks for your useful tipps. My problem is under the RequestsHandler.callService(), I have 2 cases, one case with the result need to be mocked, one not need to be mocked, that's why i dont want to mock the whole RequestsHandler

Comment: Can you explain why in one case you think that you need to mock and that you in other case you think that you don't need to mock  ?

Comment: Hi davidxxx, for example in my RequestsHandler.callService() I have 2 cases which can return the result, the first case is calling the method that will connect to the external service and get the result from it, which I  would like to mock right now. The second case is calling the method that will take the result from the cache folder in my local machine which I dont need to mock because the result from it is always stable

Comment: Hello schau, I cannot see your code but you should rely on the folder of your local machine for an unit test only if it is a requirement of your use case. About your case where you want to mock only a part of `callService()`, could you not mock at all `callService()` ? Generally either you want to rely on the real impl or you don't want to. Maybe another part of this method should be also mocked but first extracted into another class. It is abstract enough, so it is hard to give you a specific advise. But it seems to be a very interesting question. Why not ask it in another question on SO ?